# Why do Unity Colliders Pass Through One-Another at High Speeds?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0, game-physics

I have a labyrinth in my unity game, this game also has a red ball that is passing through the labyrinth, both have colliders (The ball circle colliders and the labyrinth edge colliders), it seems to work fine, but, when you drag the ball and push it into the labyrinth, passing some seconds, you can get through the colliders and pass, and, if you get enough speed, you can pass all the labyrinth like nothing!, I put in my script a speed limit (10) but it isn't working that well.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is `FixedUpdate` and using  `CollisionDetectionMode.Discrete`.

It is called N counts per second, where N is a fixed value. Physics is calculated on FixedUpdate. Now imagine situation:

1. `FixedUpdate` is called 60 times per second. Time between `FixedUpdate`
   calls is 1 second / 60 times = 17 ms (approx.)
2. Collider A size is
   1x1x1, Collider B size is 1x1x1
3. Collider A attached to still object, Collider B attached to object moving towards Collider B with speed 90 units per second.
4. Physics engine is comparing position of A and
   position of B on FixedUpdate It thinks that Collider B just
   teleported through Collider A, because it's speed per one
   FixedUpdate tick is larger, then collider's size.

[image]

If you are going to use very high speed, you have three options:

1. Try to follow **Foggzie**'s advice
2. Increase count of **FixedUpdates** per second, and avoid overloading it with scripts.
3. Implement your own physics for high-speed objects

Answer (score 2):

Unity deals with this problem through its [Collision Detection Modes](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-collisionDetectionMode.html).  Make sure your `Rigidbody` components have their `collisionDetectionMode` properties configured accordingly (they default to `Discrete`).  It seems like you'll want the ball to use `ContinuousDynamic` and the labyrinth to be `Continuous` but note, as stated in the link:

> Continuous Collision Detection is only supported for Rigidbodies with
>   Sphere-, Capsule- or BoxColliders.

You'll probably need to change the labyrinth colliders.